# Stay authenticated longer in OpenStack Horizon

Tags: openstack, administration, openstack-horizon

When administrating OpenStack through the Horizon web dashboard I get logged out often after rather short periods of inactivity. I suspect that this is caused by expiry of user JWT tokens.

Is there any way to prevent the logout? Or at least to significantly extend the time until logout? It would be especially good to have a way that doesn't require server-side changes to the Horizon setup.

Comment: What do you define as a rather short period of inactivity?

Comment: Can't say exactly but if I had to guess when I'm not using it for half an hour, I need to authenticate again. That's highly annoying.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely hitting the hour session timeout. Try setting it to something higher, e.g. `10800` to allow for up to three hours of inactivity.
https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/latest/configuration/settings.html#session-timeout